# Swing Timer issue - stop Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have been trying to stop the timer and solve this for days now, unfortunately no luck, hope someone will be able to help.

The idea is to use the timer to click a button which increases the value in the text field so I have the timer in the start button and I wish to stop it in the stop button.

That's the code I have behind my start button:

```
private void btStartTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

        javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                btAddOneActionPerformed(evt);
               }
        });
tm.start();
```

}

```
 private void btStopTimerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

}
```

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a problem of scope in your posted code: your Timer variable, tm, is declared within your start button's actionPerformed method and thus **is only visible within that method**. So you cannot get a viable reference to it when outside of that method. A solution is to declare the variable on the class level as a private instance (non-static) variable, and only call `start()` on it within your start button's action listener. This will make the variable visible throughout your class, and the stop button's listener should be able to call its methods.

e.g.,

```
package pkg3;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerDeclaration {
    private static final int DELAY = 1000;

    // the tm2 variable is visible throughout the class
    private Timer tm2 = new Timer(DELAY, new TimerListener());

    private JButton btStartTimer1 = new JButton("Start Timer 1");
    private JButton btStartTimer2 = new JButton("Start Timer 2");

    public TimerDeclaration() {
        btStartTimer1.addActionListener(e -> btStartTimer1ActionPerformed(e));
        btStartTimer2.addActionListener(e -> btStartTimer2ActionPerformed(e));
    }

    private void btStartTimer2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tm2.start(); // tm2 is visible throughout your program
    }

    private void btStartTimer1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        javax.swing.Timer tm = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                // btAddOneActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        tm.start(); // this is only visible inside here!!!
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I see an example ?

Comment: @Jamesanderson: sure. Please have a look at [these links](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A522444+swing+timer) as well as at the [Swing Timer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: do you mind showing me how it would look within my code? , sorry if I am being problematic.

Comment: @Jamesanderson: hard to say since we have only the tiniest snippets of your code. If you're still having problems, consider posting your [mcve] as recommended in the comment to your question.

Comment: hmmm thanks for the advice but could you give me a step by step of how to declare a variable on the class level as private instance(non-static) variable.

Comment: @Jamesanderson: but again the solution is simple: **get the variable declaration *outside* of the method**.

Comment: @Jamesanderson: see code above. Your last question is best answered by studying your Java text and notes. We can answer questions but basic core knowledge can only be gained through study.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help mate. Your example was excellent.

Comment: ok since the variable is visible outside of the class if i typed tm.stop(); will that then stop the timer.